# getJson inside anonother getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building some html with a getJSON call. Inside that call there's another getJSON call. I'm trying to return two variables to use in my script a few lines of code further. The problem is that the script keeps returning `undefined`. A console.log tells me that the variables return the correct answer. I do not have any errors whatsoever.

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var productsHtml = [];

    $.each(data.collection.products, function (index, product) {
        var pUrl = product.url;
        var productHtml = '' + ....blablabla....

        var stock;
        var delivery;
        $.getJSON(pUrl + '?format=json', function (data) {
            if (data.product.stock.level >= 1) {
                var stock = '<span class="ov">' + data.product.stock.level + '</span>';
                var delivery = data.product.stock.delivery.title;
            } else {
                var stock = '<span class="nov">' + data.product.stock.level + '</span>';
                var delivery = data.product.stock.delivery.title;
            }
            console.log(stock, delivery); //this returns the correct html
        });
        var productHtml = productHtml + '<li class="amount">' + stock + '</li><li class="deliverytime">' + delivery + '</li>... etcetc....
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thx in advance...